# Program embedded inside an ISO

Tags: linux, scripting, iso, payload

I'm trying to find a good way to embed some application / script inside / beside an ISO file. What I'm trying to achieve is having an cd image which can be used to kick-start its own installation via virtual-manager (`virt-install`). It's just to simplify the downloads really, so that you don't need to have an installer and an image separately.

The simplest option to do something like that would be to put uu/b64-encoded image after a bash script. The bad side of that is that the file needs to be copied again, its size is bigger than it needs to be and bash likes to reserve a lot of memory for strings that are streamed into some other program.

Another alternative is a Perl script with the binary contents after an `__END__`. That saves me from encoding the contents and high memory usage, but it doesn't prevent the copy.

Is there any elegant solution then? Are there any script languages that can be embedded inside of another file with no specific header (or at the end)? Or something that can be merged with the ISO format itself?

Comment: why not let virt-install download the image itself?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams There's some additional local preparation required. I wanted to make sure it happens before the installation itself.

Comment: Isn't there the script for that?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm not sure what you mean. There's an existing script that I'd like to merge with the .iso itself, yes. But I'd like to be able to distribute them in one file (already done, but in an awkward way described in the question).